# How to make contents on tables align to each other vertically

Tags: html, css

I have 5 tables for my content with each table unique to different content. The contents are not aligned to each other and not responsive to mobile view at all. Some content goes down inside the table some are on the top, I would like each content to be parallel to each other in the tables.

Please help

```html
    
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

 

<table style="height: 169px; float: left;" width="1200">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 160px;">
                <div id="col-737738455" class="col medium-4 small-4 large-4">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <div id="image_1560556665" class="img has-hover x md-x lg-x y md-y lg-y">
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark" style="text-align: start;"><img
                                    class="attachment-large size-large" style="float: none;"
                                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg1.jpg?v=1605257353"
                                    sizes="(max-width: 130px) 100vw, 130px"
                                    srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg1.jpg?v=1605257353" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="col-748895454" class="col medium-8 small-8 large-8">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <h3> </h3>
                        <h3> </h3>
                        <h3><strong>コットンについて</strong></h3>
                        <p>カウント（生地の折り目の密度）が高い事が特徴です。米国ではSunforger Tent
                            Canvasと呼ばれ、撥水処理・防カビ処理がコットン表面に施されています。特注の７オンスコットンは、キャンバス生地よりも細い糸を織る事により、防風性を備えながら、軽くて暖かく丈夫な事が特徴です。テントの足もとには、12インチのスノーフラップ（スカート）が全機種に標準装備。これによって、テントの幕下から入り込む冷機からを防ぎ、防寒性・保温性を高める構造となっています。
                        </p>
                        <p> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 148px;">
                <div id="col-488514215" class="col medium-4 small-4 large-4">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <div id="image_279298547" class="img has-hover x md-x lg-x y md-y lg-y">
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="col-1640372329" class="col medium-8 small-8 large-8">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <h3> </h3>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p><img class="attachment-large size-large"
                                src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg2.jpg?v=1605257353"
                                sizes="(max-width: 130px) 100vw, 130px"
                                srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg2.jpg?v=1605257353"
                                alt="" width="130" height="130" /> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <h3><strong></strong></h3>
                        <h3><strong></strong></h3>
                        <h3><strong>耐久性情報</strong></h3>
                        <p>米国の難燃性基準CPAI-84をクリアー（引火後４秒以内に自然消化。さらに燃焼距離が255mm以内であることがその基準）万一、火の粉が付着しても燃え広がることはないのが大きな特徴です。
                        </p>
                        <p><br /> ストーブジャック（ストーブの煙突を通す穴）のオレンジ色の部分（ガスケット）は、KEVLARⓇ fiber
                            と呼ばれるガラス繊維生地でつくられ、300℃程度まで耐えられる構造となっています。</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 148px;">
                <div id="col-488514215" class="col medium-4 small-4 large-4">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <div id="image_279298547" class="img has-hover x md-x lg-x y md-y lg-y">
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"><img class="attachment-large size-large"
                                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg3.jpg?v=1605257353"
                                    sizes="(max-width: 130px) 100vw, 130px"
                                    srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg3.jpg?v=1605257353"
                                    alt="" width="130" height="130" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="col-1998464481" class="col medium-8 small-8 large-8">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <h3><strong><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                                        style="vertical-align: inherit;">防水性と軽量性</span></span></strong></h3>
                        <p>さらに、撥水加工もされています。軽くて、撥水、しかも暖かい。生地の織り方と撥水加工により、生地の通気性が良い事が特徴です。例えば、完全防水のビニールようなもので覆ったテントの場合、室内温度があがるとテント内部に結露が付着してしまいます。逆に通気性が高すぎると、暖房効率が著しく落ちてしまいます。水蒸気は通すけど、水は通しにくい素材なので、冬用キャンプにぴったりなコットンテントです。
                        </p>
                        <p> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 148px;">
                <div id="col-989380329" class="col medium-4 small-4 large-4">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <div id="image_36121971" class="img has-hover x md-x lg-x y md-y lg-y">
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"><img class="attachment-large size-large"
                                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg4.jpg?v=1605257354"
                                    sizes="(max-width: 130px) 100vw, 130px"
                                    srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg4.jpg?v=1605257354"
                                    alt="" width="130" height="130" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="col-772718934" class="col medium-8 small-8 large-8">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <h3><strong>メンテナンスについて</strong></h3>
                        <p>溶剤・石鹸は使用せず、ブラシと水だけで汚れをおとします。（石鹸を使用すると表面の撥水効果を落とす為）　基本的にはメンテナンス不要ですが、もし撥水性が気になる場合には、コットン・キャンパス・ポリコットン用の撥水材をご使用下さい。
                        </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 148px;">
                <div id="col-989380329" class="col medium-4 small-4 large-4">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <div id="image_36121971" class="img has-hover x md-x lg-x y md-y lg-y">
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"><img class="attachment-large size-large"
                                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg5.jpg?v=1605257354"
                                    sizes="(max-width: 130px) 100vw, 130px"
                                    srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg5.jpg?v=1605257354"
                                    alt="" width="130" height="130" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="col-772718934" class="col medium-8 small-8 large-8">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <h3> </h3>
                        <p> </p>
                        <h3><strong><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                                        style="vertical-align: inherit;">フレームについて</span></span></strong></h3>
                        <p>米国Easton社のアルミニウムテント用フレームを使用、軽量かつ強度がある事が特徴です。 </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="section-content relative" style="text-align: left;"> </div>
<div id="row-609483721" class="row align-center" style="text-align: left;">
    <div id="col-536736672" class="col small-12 large-12">
        <h1 class="uppercase" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 130%;"><span
                    style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span style="vertical-align: inherit;">About the Brand Founders
                    </span></span></span></h1>
    </div>
</div>
<table style="height: 229px;" width="503">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 493px;">
                <p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutf1.png?v=1605488603?v=1605488265"
                        alt="" width="273" height="289" /></p>
                <p> </p>
                <p>Duane(デュアン)Margot(マーゴット)夫妻は、米国北部ウィスコンシン州で、小さな酪農場を経営して一緒に生活を始めました。彼らは常に時代の流れに逆らって、馬を飼育しながら経営を続けていましたが、産業化した大規模農場に対抗する事は難しく、酪農場を手放す決断をしました。その後、カヌーを購入し、1992年に3人の幼い息子達と一緒にウィスコンシン州北西部に転居する事を決断したのです。
                    Margot(マーゴット)は公立学校の教師としてのキャリアに戻り、その間Duane(デュアン)は主夫として、共に家庭を支えていました。家族はアウトドアライフを心から楽しみ、夏はカナダでカヌーキャンプ、冬はウィスコンシン州北部、ミネソタ州、カナダの至る所で冬用テントを使用したウィンターキャンピングに出かけました。しかし、Duane(デュアン)は満足できる冬用コットンテントがマーケットでは見つからず、自ら市販のミシンを手に入れて、コットンテント製作に取り掛かったのが、スノートレッカーテントのはじまりです。Empire
                    CanvasWorks(ECW)を立ち上げ、</p>
                <p> 12年間事業を行った後に、コットンテント製作に専念する為に事業売却を決断。</p>
                <p>その後着々とテント製作を続けていき、今日ではスノートレッカーテントは冬キャンプに最適な“ホットテント”と認知され、安全性と快適さにおいて、多くのキャンプ愛好家の皆様から好評を頂いています。</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                style="vertical-align: inherit;">SNOWTREKKER LINEUP</span></span></strong></div>
<table style="height: 345px; float: left;" width="625">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 201.204px; text-align: center;">
                <p> </p>
                <p><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span style="vertical-align: inherit;">BASECAMP
                            SERIES</span></span><img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/front_view_Basecamp_3_sizes.jpg?v=1599444797"
                        alt="basecamp tents" width="528" height="323" /><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                            style="vertical-align: inherit;">ベースキャンプは、ショートウォールシリーズよりも15cm壁面を高く設計されています。より多くの内部スペースを必要とするキャンパーに適したテントシリーズで、天井が高い事で広々とした印象とゆったりと楽しめる仕様になっています。テントフレームは、コットンで作られた収納ケースが付属。テント本体用のケースは別売りとなります。<br />
                            <br /> <br /> </span></span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 201.944px;">
                <p style="text-align: center;"> <span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                            style="vertical-align: inherit;"> SHORTWALL SERIES</span></span><img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/products/CrewShortwallBasecampall9x11_2830x.jpg?v=1599525442"
                        alt="shortwall tents" width="504" height="309" /></p>
                <p>ショートウォールは、文字通り20インチ（50.8cm）の壁面を設けたテントです。テント内で立ち上がっても十分な高さを保ちつつ、組立作業性も考慮した高さ設定となっています。水平方向の壁面フレームをロープで引っ張る事で、独特な形状を維持しています。テントフレームは、コットンで作られた収納ケースが付属。テント本体用のケースは別売りとなります。
                </p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 201.944px; text-align: center;"><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                        style="vertical-align: inherit;"> The CREW SERIES </span></span><img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/products/8x8IMG_6576_77_78_79_80_122fe804-e56d-427c-81e9-69287756c9d0_4000x.jpg?v=1599528614"
                    alt="" width="528"
                    height="323" />スノートレッカーテントの中で、最もクラシック且つ一般的なデザインアイテムです。7オンスの生地を使用し、計算された縫製、Easton社製のアルミニウムフレーム、軽く耐久性のある事から、ソロキャンプや少人数での使用に適したモデルです。テントフレームは、コットンで作られた収納ケースが付属。テント本体用のケースは別売りとなります。
            </td>
            <td style="width: 201.944px;">
                <p style="text-align: center;"> </p>
                <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                            style="vertical-align: inherit;"> MEGACREW SERIES</span></span><img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/products/Correctangleofstovepipeexitingtent_de3030bb-ed17-49ae-87ca-9996fa98c49a_1200x.jpg?v=1599542260"
                        alt="megacrew tents" width="504" height="309" /></p>
                <p>メガクルーは、スノートレッカーテントの中で一番サイズの大きい商品となります。広々とした室内空間。有効スペースを広くとる為に、テント側面のサイドポールの位置が高く設定されているので、ゆったりとした空間で過ごす事ができます。フレームは、Easton社１3/4インチのアルミニウムフレームを使用し、大型テントでありながらも軽さと強さを実現しています。
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you use bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

td .attachment-large {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

 

<table style="height: 169px; float: left;" width="1200">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 160px;">
                <div id="col-737738455" class="col medium-4 small-4 large-4">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <div id="image_1560556665" class="img has-hover x md-x lg-x y md-y lg-y">
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark" style="text-align: start;"><img
                                    class="attachment-large size-large" style="float: none;"
                                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg1.jpg?v=1605257353"
                                    sizes="(max-width: 130px) 100vw, 130px"
                                    srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg1.jpg?v=1605257353" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="col-748895454" class="col medium-8 small-8 large-8">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <h3><strong>コットンについて</strong></h3>
                        <p>カウント（生地の折り目の密度）が高い事が特徴です。米国ではSunforger Tent
                            Canvasと呼ばれ、撥水処理・防カビ処理がコットン表面に施されています。特注の７オンスコットンは、キャンバス生地よりも細い糸を織る事により、防風性を備えながら、軽くて暖かく丈夫な事が特徴です。テントの足もとには、12インチのスノーフラップ（スカート）が全機種に標準装備。これによって、テントの幕下から入り込む冷機からを防ぎ、防寒性・保温性を高める構造となっています。
                        </p>
                        <p> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 148px;">
                <div id="col-488514215" class="col medium-4 small-4 large-4">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <div id="image_279298547" class="img has-hover x md-x lg-x y md-y lg-y">
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="col-1640372329" class="col medium-8 small-8 large-8">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <p><img class="attachment-large size-large"
                                src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg2.jpg?v=1605257353"
                                sizes="(max-width: 130px) 100vw, 130px"
                                srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg2.jpg?v=1605257353"
                                alt="" width="130" height="130" /> </p>
                        <h3><strong>耐久性情報</strong></h3>
                        <p>米国の難燃性基準CPAI-84をクリアー（引火後４秒以内に自然消化。さらに燃焼距離が255mm以内であることがその基準）万一、火の粉が付着しても燃え広がることはないのが大きな特徴です。
                        </p>
                        <p><br /> ストーブジャック（ストーブの煙突を通す穴）のオレンジ色の部分（ガスケット）は、KEVLARⓇ fiber
                            と呼ばれるガラス繊維生地でつくられ、300℃程度まで耐えられる構造となっています。</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 148px;">
                <div id="col-488514215" class="col medium-4 small-4 large-4">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <div id="image_279298547" class="img has-hover x md-x lg-x y md-y lg-y">
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"></div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"><img class="attachment-large size-large"
                                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg3.jpg?v=1605257353"
                                    sizes="(max-width: 130px) 100vw, 130px"
                                    srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg3.jpg?v=1605257353"
                                    alt="" width="130" height="130" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="col-1998464481" class="col medium-8 small-8 large-8">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <h3><strong><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                                        style="vertical-align: inherit;">防水性と軽量性</span></span></strong></h3>
                        <p>さらに、撥水加工もされています。軽くて、撥水、しかも暖かい。生地の織り方と撥水加工により、生地の通気性が良い事が特徴です。例えば、完全防水のビニールようなもので覆ったテントの場合、室内温度があがるとテント内部に結露が付着してしまいます。逆に通気性が高すぎると、暖房効率が著しく落ちてしまいます。水蒸気は通すけど、水は通しにくい素材なので、冬用キャンプにぴったりなコットンテントです。
                        </p>
                        <p> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 148px;">
                <div id="col-989380329" class="col medium-4 small-4 large-4">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <div id="image_36121971" class="img has-hover x md-x lg-x y md-y lg-y">
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"><img class="attachment-large size-large"
                                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg4.jpg?v=1605257354"
                                    sizes="(max-width: 130px) 100vw, 130px"
                                    srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg4.jpg?v=1605257354"
                                    alt="" width="130" height="130" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="col-772718934" class="col medium-8 small-8 large-8">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <h3><strong>メンテナンスについて</strong></h3>
                        <p>溶剤・石鹸は使用せず、ブラシと水だけで汚れをおとします。（石鹸を使用すると表面の撥水効果を落とす為）　基本的にはメンテナンス不要ですが、もし撥水性が気になる場合には、コットン・キャンパス・ポリコットン用の撥水材をご使用下さい。
                        </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 148px;">
                <div id="col-989380329" class="col medium-4 small-4 large-4">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <div id="image_36121971" class="img has-hover x md-x lg-x y md-y lg-y">
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"> </div>
                            <div class="img-inner dark"><img class="attachment-large size-large"
                                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg5.jpg?v=1605257354"
                                    sizes="(max-width: 130px) 100vw, 130px"
                                    srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutimg5.jpg?v=1605257354"
                                    alt="" width="130" height="130" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="col-772718934" class="col medium-8 small-8 large-8">
                    <div class="col-inner">
                        <h3> </h3>
                        <p> </p>
                        <h3><strong><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                                        style="vertical-align: inherit;">フレームについて</span></span></strong></h3>
                        <p>米国Easton社のアルミニウムテント用フレームを使用、軽量かつ強度がある事が特徴です。 </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                        <p> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="section-content relative" style="text-align: left;"> </div>
<div id="row-609483721" class="row align-center" style="text-align: left;">
    <div id="col-536736672" class="col small-12 large-12">
        <h1 class="uppercase" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 130%;"><span
                    style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span style="vertical-align: inherit;">About the Brand Founders
                    </span></span></span></h1>
    </div>
</div>
<table style="height: 229px;" width="503">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 493px;">
                <p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/aboutf1.png?v=1605488603?v=1605488265"
                        alt="" width="273" height="289" /></p>
                <p> </p>
                <p>Duane(デュアン)Margot(マーゴット)夫妻は、米国北部ウィスコンシン州で、小さな酪農場を経営して一緒に生活を始めました。彼らは常に時代の流れに逆らって、馬を飼育しながら経営を続けていましたが、産業化した大規模農場に対抗する事は難しく、酪農場を手放す決断をしました。その後、カヌーを購入し、1992年に3人の幼い息子達と一緒にウィスコンシン州北西部に転居する事を決断したのです。
                    Margot(マーゴット)は公立学校の教師としてのキャリアに戻り、その間Duane(デュアン)は主夫として、共に家庭を支えていました。家族はアウトドアライフを心から楽しみ、夏はカナダでカヌーキャンプ、冬はウィスコンシン州北部、ミネソタ州、カナダの至る所で冬用テントを使用したウィンターキャンピングに出かけました。しかし、Duane(デュアン)は満足できる冬用コットンテントがマーケットでは見つからず、自ら市販のミシンを手に入れて、コットンテント製作に取り掛かったのが、スノートレッカーテントのはじまりです。Empire
                    CanvasWorks(ECW)を立ち上げ、</p>
                <p> 12年間事業を行った後に、コットンテント製作に専念する為に事業売却を決断。</p>
                <p>その後着々とテント製作を続けていき、今日ではスノートレッカーテントは冬キャンプに最適な“ホットテント”と認知され、安全性と快適さにおいて、多くのキャンプ愛好家の皆様から好評を頂いています。</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                style="vertical-align: inherit;">SNOWTREKKER LINEUP</span></span></strong></div>
<table style="height: 345px; float: left;" width="625">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 201.204px; text-align: center;">
                <p> </p>
                <p><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span style="vertical-align: inherit;">BASECAMP
                            SERIES</span></span><img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/files/front_view_Basecamp_3_sizes.jpg?v=1599444797"
                        alt="basecamp tents" width="528" height="323" /><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                            style="vertical-align: inherit;">ベースキャンプは、ショートウォールシリーズよりも15cm壁面を高く設計されています。より多くの内部スペースを必要とするキャンパーに適したテントシリーズで、天井が高い事で広々とした印象とゆったりと楽しめる仕様になっています。テントフレームは、コットンで作られた収納ケースが付属。テント本体用のケースは別売りとなります。<br />
                            <br /> <br /> </span></span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 201.944px;">
                <p style="text-align: center;"> <span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                            style="vertical-align: inherit;"> SHORTWALL SERIES</span></span><img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/products/CrewShortwallBasecampall9x11_2830x.jpg?v=1599525442"
                        alt="shortwall tents" width="504" height="309" /></p>
                <p>ショートウォールは、文字通り20インチ（50.8cm）の壁面を設けたテントです。テント内で立ち上がっても十分な高さを保ちつつ、組立作業性も考慮した高さ設定となっています。水平方向の壁面フレームをロープで引っ張る事で、独特な形状を維持しています。テントフレームは、コットンで作られた収納ケースが付属。テント本体用のケースは別売りとなります。
                </p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 201.944px; text-align: center;"><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                        style="vertical-align: inherit;"> The CREW SERIES </span></span><img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/products/8x8IMG_6576_77_78_79_80_122fe804-e56d-427c-81e9-69287756c9d0_4000x.jpg?v=1599528614"
                    alt="" width="528"
                    height="323" />スノートレッカーテントの中で、最もクラシック且つ一般的なデザインアイテムです。7オンスの生地を使用し、計算された縫製、Easton社製のアルミニウムフレーム、軽く耐久性のある事から、ソロキャンプや少人数での使用に適したモデルです。テントフレームは、コットンで作られた収納ケースが付属。テント本体用のケースは別売りとなります。
            </td>
            <td style="width: 201.944px;">
                <p style="text-align: center;"> </p>
                <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="vertical-align: inherit;"><span
                            style="vertical-align: inherit;"> MEGACREW SERIES</span></span><img
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/8659/9332/products/Correctangleofstovepipeexitingtent_de3030bb-ed17-49ae-87ca-9996fa98c49a_1200x.jpg?v=1599542260"
                        alt="megacrew tents" width="504" height="309" /></p>
                <p>メガクルーは、スノートレッカーテントの中で一番サイズの大きい商品となります。広々とした室内空間。有効スペースを広くとる為に、テント側面のサイドポールの位置が高く設定されているので、ゆったりとした空間で過ごす事ができます。フレームは、Easton社１3/4インチのアルミニウムフレームを使用し、大型テントでありながらも軽さと強さを実現しています。
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The added CSS sets the content of the table cells to align to the top and sets the images to have the same height. Then, removing empty elements like `<p></p>` and `<h3></h3>` removes the remaining whitespace.